# Can sludge in septic tank prevent water from draining into the ground

Tags: drain, septic

I am just wondering whether sludge that settles at the bottom of the septic tank can block the water from draining(discharging) into the ground.

If yes then what are the steps that we have to take to prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be any flow from the bottom of the tank into the ground.  There is an outflow line that leads to the leach field that is usually on the side opposite from the inflow port.

If you have "sludge" built up on the bottom the usual fix is to have the tank pumped out.  For most installations this should be done every 12-18 months or as recommended by your septic tank service company.

What you want to avoid is having solids rise to the level of the outflow port and get into the leach field.  This will clog up the soil and slow down or stop the ability of it to allow water to pass through.  That can end up being a VERY expensive problem to fix.

Regular maintenance is a LOT less expensive than repairs!

Comment: Thanks for the insight.